# How to view a sliders value in bundle settings , iOS?

Tags: ios, slider, settings, settings.bundle

I am using a slider in the bundle settings of my app to make the user choose a distance between 1 - 1000 meters.

The slider is working fine , but i would like to show the user the actual value of the slider.

Is this possible?

Comment: to clarify what you are looking for, I need to show the selected value *inside* the Setting App or in your own application?

Comment: In the bundle settings. In the settings menu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think there is no viable possibility to do this with a slider. You could use a `PSMultiValueSpecifier`, a "Multi Value Element" instead, with 4 sections, one for each digit of your 4-digit number. It could then be set and displayed at the same time.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Hm i dont really understand what you are describing. Can you maybe google for an image and post it along?

Comment: No, sorry, but it's all in the documentation: [here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/PreferenceSettings/Conceptual/SettingsApplicationSchemaReference/Articles/PSMultiValueSpecifier.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007016-SW1).

Comment: If i create a text view , and tell the user to type a number , is there a way to limit the max length of the string he types in 3 digits? so that he cant type something bigger than 999m ?

Comment: `PSMultiValueSpecifier` creates a new separate view from the main one, and it's not the behaviour asked by this question owner.