# Add value display to slider in iOS Settings Pane

Tags: ios, settings

I've successfully added a slider to the iPhone Settings app’s preference pane. Works like a charm. However, I’d like to inform the user of the exact value he chose, or, to be more specific, enable the user to enter a specific value using the slider.

So: **Is there a way to display the value the user chose, preferably live-updating while the user moves the slider?**

*Edit: I know how to do that in my own app’s handmade preferences view. I’m specifically asking how to do this within a Settings.bundle, so that the pane will show up in my app’s section within Settings.app. I fear it’s impossible.*

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14975360/how-to-view-a-sliders-value-in-bundle-settings-ios